# ios - UITableView Section Index Titles - not many titles => spread out letters?

Tags: ios, uitableview

So I have a UITableView that I'm using with Section Index Titles.. but I'm not using the entire alphabet, only the individual letters required.

But the way it does this, is by even spacing each of the letters out like the two examples below:

[image: really spaced]  [image: highly spaced]

So, is there anyway I can force it to just show them consecutively w/o so much spacing? Maybe adjust the frame or insets?

Thank you,
rnc505

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure you are stuck with the even distribution across the height of the table view frame.

Adjusting the frame would not help as this would affect the frame of the entire table view.

If you want to create an index view with a custom height you will need to do so with a custom view.

Answer (score 0):

This is solved by Apple in iOS7. From iOS7 the available index titles are centered in the center at the right. But they lowered the maximum number before showing dots a lot. Only half the entries fit now. I filed a radar for that one (15175436).